# take the result from JS to CI

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

i stuck with this one,, i want the the result from js to CI.. i want got string type data from js, and sendback it to CI.
this is my code:

```
<?php $i=0; foreach ($bahanx as $pin2){ ?> <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write("<div class='input-group' style='width:175%'><label class='input-group-addon' style='width:100px'><input type='checkbox' name='bahan' aria-label='Checkbox for following text input' value="+<?php echo $pin2->id_barang ?>+" oninput='changeText(this,"+<?php echo $i ?>+");' > <?php echo $pin2->nama_barang;?></label><input type='text' class='form-control' aria-label='Text input with checkbox' name='banyak_bahan' value='0' disabled/></div><br/>");
    </script>
<?php
$i++; } ?>
```

and this:

```
var item_box = document.getElementsByName('banyak_bahan');
var item_name = document.getElementsByName('bahan');
var tot;
function changeText(e,i){
  item_name[i].value = e.checked ? 1 : 0;
  item_box[i].disabled = !e.checked;
  var x=x+","+item_box[i];
  var y=y+","+item_name[i];
  //alert(x);
  document.getElementById('fff').innerHTML=x+"<br/>"+y;
}
```

id=fff

```
<div id='fff'></div>
```

the result:

> undefined,[object HTMLInputElement]
>   undefined,[object HTMLInputElement]

Answer (score 1):

Try this you have invalid js string thats because you print `+<?php echo $aaa;?>+` inside try to delete `+`

**UPDATE:** try this to echo from php directly.

```
<?php
$i=0;
 foreach ($bahanx as $pin2){ 
      echo "<div class='input-group' style='width:175%'><label class='input-group-addon' style='width:100px'><input type='checkbox' name='bahan' aria-label='Checkbox for following text input' value='".$pin2->id_barang."' oninput='changeText(this,".$i.");' > ". $pin2->nama_barang ."</label><input type='text' class='form-control' aria-label='Text input with checkbox' name='banyak_bahan' value='0' disabled/></div><br/>";
      $i++; 
 } 
 ?>
```

instead of this

```
<?php $i=0; foreach ($bahanx as $pin2){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write("<div class='input-group' style='width:175%'><label class='input-group-addon' style='width:100px'><input type='checkbox' name='bahan' aria-label='Checkbox for following text input' value="<?php echo $pin2->id_barang; ?>" oninput='changeText(this,"<?php echo $i; ?>");' > <?php echo $pin2->nama_barang; ?></label><input type='text' class='form-control' aria-label='Text input with checkbox' name='banyak_bahan' value='0' disabled/></div><br/>");
    </script>
    <?php $i++; } ?>
```

**UPDATE:** you saw x & y is not defined thats number one , to get value of checkbox element you must use `item_name[i].value`, `item_box[i].value`

```
var item_box = document.getElementsByName('banyak_bahan');
var item_name = document.getElementsByName('bahan');
var tot;
function changeText(e,i){
  item_name[i].value = e.checked ? 1 : 0;
  item_box[i].disabled = !e.checked;
  var x= item_box[i].value;
  var y= item_name[i].value;
  //alert(x);
  document.getElementById('fff').innerHTML=x+"<br/>"+y;
}
```

Comment: i try it, but still same with mine

Comment: i saw `var x=x+","+item_box[i];` is `x` and `y` variable defined before?

Comment: thanks b4, but now the result only take the last checkbox's value.. the increment didnt work

Comment: Why do you want to use `document.write()` ?  you can echo directly from PHP.

Comment: Try to echo directly from PHP.

Comment: Sure, PHP will echo the HTML divs and JavaScript function will do the task.

Comment: then, how i can pass the value in js to html name or CI?